SPSS R integration
How do you install packages in SPSS R integration?
I am always getting non-zero exit status error message even though I tried to install dependencies.

Install your dependencies first then your final one, or install.packages('pak'), library(pak), pak::pak(the library you want), pak will handle all dependencies ( and dependencies dependencies). You'll want package 'foreign` also. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Read error messages. You are missing package “fs”. Install it.

Start by installing just fs by itself, and report the error messages you get.

Thank you all, I tried with pak and fs. I got this error message:
Warning message:
In install.packages("fs") :
installation of package ‘fs’ had non-zero exit status                                             In install.packages("pak") :
installation of package ‘pak’ had non-zero exit status
